# timeout a job on jboss

Tags: java, jboss

i'm running jboss AS 4.2 with java 1.6 and my problem is as follows:
our application is distributed as an ear and a war containing some servlets.
these servlets call the needed EJBs which do some processing and then return the result.

i'm looking for a way to determine a timeout, which in case the processing takes too much time, and it'll just return and end the processing (the processing involves several EJBs).

i can use ThreadLocal and add some code that will check at the beginning of each method if it exceeded the time - but is there some other mechanism i can use without adding such code to my application?

any idea / reference will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be different ways, but very first thing comming to my mind based on your requiremens are interceptors.

So that you would intercept all your problematic (possibly long taking calls) and throw exception in case they exceeded the time.

And yes, threadlocal could do the job for keeping the start time (In case you don't use asynchronous stateless session bean calls).

To get some idea, of what interceptors are capable of, see: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/interceptors_ejb_3_for_absolute

The main advantage of this solution is that you would have clear separation of timeout functionality (in Interceptor) from your bussiness logic (in EJBs).

Comment: Thank you very much, this will do the trick. just need to add the interceptor annotations to my EJBs.

My calls are synchronous, so i'll use it.

Comment: correct, another advantage you might have is the possiblity of xml configuration (at least it worked for us when we used JBoss + JBoss AOP) where you don't even need to change your EJB logic and mapping rules are usually question of one line in XML. On the other hand, you would not see the mapping in the EJB code itself.